# IntelliJ IDEA Annotation processors: "Obtain processors from project classpath"

Tags: android, intellij-idea, annotation-processing

What does the "Obtain processors from project classpath" option in the annotation processor settings mean? 
If I understand the option "Obtain processors from project classpath" correctly, it should scan the classpath and find all annotation processors automatically.

However, this doesn't seem to work that way. I have a project with annotation processors added to the project classpath (android annotations). When selecting "Obtain processors from project classpath", they are not executed. I must specify them explicitly in the "Processor path" to get them working.

When I run the build in maven, the annotation processors are executed.

Is this a bug in IntelliJ IDEA or am I just understanding the setting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with the annotation processors in IntelliJ. I've filed a bug and they fixed it in **IDEA 12.1**:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94749

Comment: Hmm, hopefully Android Studio pulls in the upstream changes from 12.1 soon!